# Remove page number on first page (but not others), and keep header on all pages

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the page number of the first page but keep the header. I want the page numbers to display on all other pages (along with the headers). So far from what I've tried, `\thispagestyle{empty}` removes the header, and `\fancyfoot{}` works for page one but I can't get the page numbers to return on page 2.

Any easy ways to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code,  then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You can make several styles defined as you want, and then  use `\thispagestyle{mystyle}` and `\pagestyle{myotherstyle}` whenever you want,    but a first page usually should be enough clear about you are reading without any header ...

Comment: How or where is `\fancyfoot` defined? If you're using the `fancyhdr` package, please do tell us how you've set up your preferred page layout and where on the page the page number is placed by default.